# Near protocol sandbox Promise::new().transfer() doesn't work

Tags: rust, promise, nearprotocol

I am developing a NEAR protocol smart contract that has a function which sends $NEAR from the contract account to another account.

The function works fine in testnet, but when I try to run it inside the sandbox the $NEAR transfer never occurs, causing my tests to fail.

Even though the contract works in testnet, this problem is slowing down my entire testing pipeline and making the team insecure about lots of contract assertions.

The function code is basically:

```
pub fn retrieve_dev_funds(&mut self) -> Promise {
        let dev_account_id = self.owner_id.clone();
        let withdrawal_dev_balance = self.dev_balance.clone();
        self.dev_balance = 0;
        Promise::new(dev_account_id).transfer(withdrawal_dev_balance)
    }
```

And the test code is:

```
let devBalance1 = contractState.dev_balance;
let devNearBalance1 = await devUser.getAccountBalance();

let promiseTransfer = await hodler1CoinUser.retrieve_dev_funds({ args: {} });
console.log(promiseTransfer);
await hodler1CoinUser.play({ args: { _bet_type: true, bet_size: betSize } })

let contractState2 = await hodler1CoinUser.get_contract_state({ args: {} });
let devBalance2 = contractState2.dev_balance;
let devNearBalance2 = await devUser.getAccountBalance();


assert.equal(devBalance2, "0");
   assert.equal(BigNumber(devNearBalance1.total).plus(BigNumber(devBalance1)).comparedTo(BigNumber(devNearBalance2.total)), 0);
```

The test fails at the last assertion as devNearBalance2 is actually equal to devNearBalance1, since the Promise transfer never actually happens.